# Nginx subdomain (and domain) not working

Tags: nginx

I'm on windows 7 x32 and this my nginx file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    upstream app_opencubes {
        server 127.0.0.1:1234;
    }   

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.opencubes.io opencubes.io;

        #charset koi8-r;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://app_opencubes/;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  my.opencubes.io;

        #charset koi8-r;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://app_opencubes/dashboard/;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


    }


}
```

Whenever I try to reach `opencubes.io` or `my.opencubes.io`, my browser says can't load url. But when I try localhost it works

Comment: Have you got the dns records for the domain set up properly?

Comment: @CameronMartin where? In the hosts file?

Comment: Have you bought this domain, or do you just want to be able to access it on your computer only?

Comment: No, just on my computer locally.

Comment: I guess you've added those entries to the hosts file?

Comment: Now yes, see anwser Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK I need to add this to `C:/window/system32/drivers/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       opencubes.io
127.0.0.1       my.opencubes.io
```